# BeautifulSoup: Can't find Tag with text it contains

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I have troubles finding a tag using the text it contains on the following page:
[Link to web page](https://www.marketscreener.com/FLUTTER-ENTERTAINMENT-PLC-59029817/company/)

I am trying to find the Bloomberg and Reuters codes using the following code.
Using cssSelector i tried:

```
css_selector = 'tr:has(> td:contains("Bloomberg Code"))'
my_tag: Tag = my_soup.select_one(css_selector)
```

Using find I tried:

```
my_tag = my_soup.find(lambda t: t.Tag == 'td' and re.findall('Bloomberg Code', t.text, flags=re.I))
```

They both return a massive amount of Html code, which does start by the tag "tr", but doesn't match what i was expecting to be:

```
<tr>
    <td style="padding-top:5px">- Bloomberg Code : </td>
    <td style="padding-left:10px;padding-top:5px" align="left">&nbsp;FLTR:ID</td>
</tr>
```

I think the issue might be that Beautifulsoup sees it as a navigable string, but when i check type of result found for my_tag it says: class 'bs4.element.Tag'

Thanks for the help
Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a User-Agent header and want the adjacent sibling `td` of the `td` which contains search term.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

search_strings = ['Bloomberg Code :',' Reuters Code :']
r = requests.get('https://www.marketscreener.com/FLUTTER-ENTERTAINMENT-PLC-59029817/company/', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

for search_string in search_strings:
    node = soup.select_one(f'td:contains("{search_string}") + td')
    if node is None:
        print(f'{search_string} not found')
    else:
        print(node.text)
```

Comment: tx so much for using css_selector. I have just started with these and I wonder what means 'f' front of "'td:contains("{search_string}") + td'". As well the " + td" in the end, would you mind explaining?
I was using headers but will mention next time, as i aperciate might be a robot issue. tx again

Comment: Hi, the f is for [f strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#how-to-denote-f-strings) / also [this](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/);  and the + is a [css adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)